# Django update form values on page refresh

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have a class in forms.py that set the ui for that form, some of which are a drop down menu populated by an (external) database

```
class myForm(forms.Form):

    barcodes_list = getBarcodes(server_database) 
    barcodes= forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Barcodes', 
        choices=barcodes_list,
         widget=forms.Select(attrs={'style':'width:164px'}),
          initial = ''  )
```

the barcodes_list is only ran on restart of the Django server. If the page is refreshed the barcode list stays the same even if there was a change on the database. I would like barcodes_list to be run again on refresh.

I have tried adding this within the myForm class as per similar questions on SO

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        barcodes_list = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['barcodes'].choices = getBarcodes(server_database)

    barcodes = forms.TypedChoiceField(label='Barcodes',
         widget=forms.Select(attrs={'style':'width:164px'}), initial='')
```